# C While loop behaving funny

Tags: c

I have a while loop that manipulates over the variable 'top', a pointer running down a linked list until some conditions are met. No big deal.

Outside the loop, when I try to make another node on my list point to 'top', I get an infinite loop of gibberish.

I don't understand why this is happening, because I'm already outside the loop!

Code:

```
//defining a node
struct Node
{
    int info;
    int frequency;
    struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;

//the loop
while(top->info != p->info && top->frequency != frequency && top != NULL && top != p)
{   
    last = top;
    top = top->next;
}

//the problem
o->next = p->next;
last->next = p;
p->next = top; //when I remove this line, everything works just fine
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you're trying to put a node before the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
top->info != p->info && top->frequency != frequency && top != NULL && top != p
```

does not make much sense.

If it's possible that `top == NULL`, then you need to check that *before* you get to `top->info` (since otherwise the latter can try to dereference a null pointer). Your compiler may well have detected that this condition does not make sense, and optimized the resulting code in a way that makes the bug show up as bizarre behavior.

Another reason this condition doesn't make sense is that it's redundant to check that `top != p` after checking that `top->info != p->info`, since the latter entails the former; but at least this one will not cause undefined behavior.

If you change the condition to make more sense:

```
top != NULL && top->info != p->info && top->frequency != frequency
```

you'll likely find that the problem goes away.

Comment: Well, it is true that `top->info != p->info` is redundant. I was trying to fix the error and ended up doing some nasty stuff in the code... I'm using GCC, by the way. I will try to fix in you way

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the top pointer is pointing to some garbage value? It may have reached NULL, and then you have assigned that value to p->next. Top will retain whatever last value it had during the loop. It doesn't get reset upon coming out. So, top no longer points to the first element in the list after the loop.